# Chat Messages screen doesn't update message screen after post message using expo-react native-typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, axios, expo

I'm trying to learning about chat app using expo-react native-typescript. What im doing so far is like below :

ChatRoomScreen.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { useRoute, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import MessageInput from '../components/MessageInput'

// api client
import axios from 'axios';

const ChatRoomScreen = () => {

    const route = useRoute()
    const mounted = useRef(true);
    const roomID = route.params?.id
    const user = route.params?.user
    const isMe = route.params?.isMe

    const [message, setMessage] = useState();
    
    //AxiosRequest
    //get chats
    const fetchMessages = async () =>{
        axios.get('https://mylaravelAPI.com/api/get/'+roomID)
        .then(function (response) {

            // handle success
            const result = response.data.message.reverse();
            {setMessage(result)}         
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMessages()
    },[])

 
    return (
        
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.page}>            
            <FlatList               
                data={message}

                //Send params to Message
                renderItem={({item}) => <Message message={item} roomID={roomID}/> }
                inverted                
            />
            <MessageInput 

                //Send params to MessageInput
                id={route.params?.id} 
                receiveID={route.params?.user} 
                userID={route.params?.isMe} 
            />
        </SafeAreaView>        
        
    )
}

export default ChatRoomScreen
```

Message.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

const blue = '#3777f0'
const grey = 'lightgrey'

const myID = '1'

const Message = ({ message, roomID }) => { 

    const isMe = message.user.id == myID
    const roomId = roomID

    return (
        <View style={[
            styles.container, isMe ? styles.rightContainer : styles.leftContainer]}
        >
            <Text style={{ color: isMe ? 'black' : 'white' }}>{message.content}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Message
```

MessageInput.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import { SimpleLineIcons, Feather, MaterialCommunityIcons, AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import MessageComponent from "../Message";

// api client
import axios from 'axios';

const MessageInput = ({id, receiveID, userID}) => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState()

    const chatroom = id
    const senderUserID = userID.id
    const receiveUserID = receiveID.id

    //Action
    //save message
    const saveMessage = () => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://mylaravelAPI.com/api/post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            }, 
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "content": message,
                "userID": senderUserID,
                "replyToID": receiveUserID
            })
        });

        setMessage('')
    }

    //update message
    const updateMessage = () => {
        console.log('updateMessage')
    }

    //OnPress
    const onPress2 = () => {
        if (chatroom === null) {
            {saveMessage()}
        }else{
            {updateMessage()}
        }
    }

    const onPress = () => {
        // console.log(message)        
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.root}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <SimpleLineIcons name='emotsmile' size={24} color='#595959' style={styles.icon}/>

                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={message}
                    onChangeText={setMessage}
                    placeholder="Signal message..."
                />

                <Feather name='camera' size={24} color='#595959' style={styles.icon}/>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='microphone-outline' size={24} color='#595959' style={styles.icon}/>
                
            </View>
            {/* <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                {message ? <Ionicons name="send" size={18} color="white" /> : <AntDesign name='plus' size={24} color='white' />}
            </Pressable> */}
            <View onPress={onPress} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                {message ? 
                    <Pressable 
                        onPress={onPress2}>
                        <Ionicons name="send" size={18} color="white" />
                    </Pressable> :
                    <Pressable 
                        onPress={onPress}>
                        <AntDesign name='plus' size={24} color='white' />
                    </Pressable>
                    
                    }
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default MessageInput
```

Everything is working except the message not update or shows ini realtime. It's will show only when i go back to Welcome screen and open the chat/room again... please help me.. thanks